# SharePoint 2010 WebPart Configuration File

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Where is it best practice to set up the configuration such as connection strings or web service URL's in SharePoint 2010's Web Parts?

Web parts do not contain a web.config or an app.config and for good reason.  So i wanted to know what everyone else does.

Would it be a good idea to create another assembly file along with your project?

Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPart refers the configuration file **web.config** of the Web Site where it is deployed to. So we all use **web.config** for storing all the configuration.
Below Links will help you to get the value from the Web.Config

1. To Read [Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx).
2. To Read [application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx).